# Cakephp 3.2 Users can't Log in

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, authentication

I am working on a personal project and I have searched through multiple topics that are related to my issue and I cannot find a solution to my problem. 
Whenever I enter an email and password on my login page it always give me an invalid username or password pop up. I debugged a part of code in my UserloginController and it just returns false. There is probably a problem here but i cannot see it. 
Some solutions for other people were to change the VARCHAR length of the password field, my password field is already a VARCHAR(255) and it hashes properly so this is not the problem.
Here is my AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function isAuthorized($user = null)
    {
        // Any registered user can access public functions
        if (empty($this->request->params['prefix'])) {
            return true;
        }

        // Only admins can access admin functions
        if ($this->request->params['prefix'] === 'admin') {
            return (bool)($user['role'] === 'admin');
        }

        // Default deny
        return false;
    }
    public function initialize()
    {


        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'userModel' => 'userlogin',
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'userlogin',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
                'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'userlogin', 
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
        ]);

        // Allow the display action so our pages controller
        // continues to work.
        $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
    }

    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my UserLoginController

```
class UserloginController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->Auth->allow(['logout', 'add']);
    }

    //login
    public function login(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            debug($this->Auth->identify()); // Returns False
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                }
            $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
    $this->Flash->success('You are now logged out.');
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow('logout', 'login', 'index', 'add'); //you can add others here...
    }

}
```

And Here is my Login.ctp

```
<br>
<div class="index large-4 medium-4 large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
<h1>Login</h1>
<?= $this->Form->create(); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('email'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('password'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Login'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Any sort of help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can print actual username and password which is using in identify() function. And see whether both hashes are correct. If not you may fix it. I am little bit confuse with names you used for Controllers and for Models. Usually there is a naming convention. If you explicitly didn't call for the model in your usersloginController, then any model will not be automatically loading.

Comment: The password does hash correctly, So i don't think that is the problem. If you want i can post my file in the Entity folder. Yes usually the controller is set to user, but I am using the user table for something else so i made a userlogin table just for logging in. So I am guessing this is the problem. How should i call for the model?

Comment: I don't know how successfull this is; but can you do `debug($user);` instead of `debug($this->Auth->identify());`. You are calling identify() method twice. Other than that, I am unable to see any further error. If this also fails, let me try this with CakePhp 3.0. And please set a auth redirect url in auth config.